# php: Where should I put my autoloader in a zend project directory structure

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I have a function below to autoload classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
})
```

Looking at [zend's recommended directory structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html) I'm confused where an autoloader like this would be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your autoload function specifies `classes/` relatively, it should be a sibling file to that directory.

However, if you specify an absolute path to the classes directory, it really doesn't matter where you put your autoload file, so long as the organizational aspect makes sense to you -

And of course, the sooner it is referenced from your application's point of entry, the more sense it will make to other people.

Comment: I shouldn't have put that path in there or make it clear this was a more general question about where you usually put an autoloader like this in a zend project, but from you comment I can surmise the exact location is not overly important. Thanks.